# automatic speech detection and recording

Tags: c#

I am new to coding in c#. I am building an application to detect the speech and automatically record it. All the information available is based on windows speech recognition engine but my requirement is, the program should detect the speech and record it.

after recording that file is used for processing using `hidden markov model(HMM)`.

```
namespace Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

   private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
        {
            sources.Add(NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
        }

        sourceList.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(source.ProductName);
            item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, source.Channels.ToString()));
            sourceList.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }

    NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;
    NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = null;
    NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveWriter = null;


  private void button_2_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

        int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

        sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
        waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter("test.wav", sourceStream.WaveFormat);
        sourceStream.StartRecording();

    }


    private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {

        if (waveWriter == null) return;
        waveWriter.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        waveWriter.Flush();

    }


   private void button_3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (waveOut != null)
            {
                waveOut.Stop();
                waveOut.Dispose();
                waveOut = null;
            }
            if (sourceStream != null)
            {
                sourceStream.StopRecording();
                sourceStream.Dispose();
                sourceStream = null;
            }
            if (waveWriter != null)
            {
                waveWriter.Dispose();
                waveWriter = null;
            }

            speechprocessing.Model_test.speech();
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

this suits my requirement but it has two button to initiate and terminate the recording process which is not under my requirement..

the program should be running and when the speech is detected it must be recorded and further processed. the words which it should detect is also not too much only a few set of words for which we have made the models using `hidden markov model`..

so please help me out from this problem.

Comment: @TFrost that edit did not "improve formatting". The indentaion is still off and there's a rogue `}` at the end. Also the entire post is in lowercase. Try to suggest more substantial edits. Fix all obvious flaws, or don't bother at all.

Comment: @codeCaster : I've corrected the rouge `}`. And for other issue : post being in the lowercase,  Minor English errors are understandable, it hasn't caused any distractions or isn't unreadable. If I edit the post looking for each grammatical mistake, uppercase or lowercase  I am being a Grammar-Nazi and It wouldn't neither help the OP nor the site. Thnx for suggestion anyway.

Comment: @TFrost now you suggested `inline code` for random terms. You shouldn't. And by fixing grammar or capitalization, you _are_ increasing readability, not being a grammar nazi. Read [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts), [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ok now that I have read the article I will try to improve my mistakes. As for inline code : I just had to edit one `}` but edit requires at least 6 character changes so I used inline code to highlight hidden markov model(HMM). It is not random, it's more specific in terms of OP's case. Yeah I know I should have not have used `inline code` but what has been done is done. reject the edit..